# Custom or override accessor with property

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessor

Two similar questions

Question 1: I’ve a custom setter called mySetter:, is stockName still hold strong pointer?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, setter = mySetter:) NSString *stockName;
- (void)mySetter:(NSString *)name {
    _stockName = name;
}
```

Question 2: I’ve override default setter, is stockName still hold strong pointer too?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *stockName;
- (void)setStockName:(NSString *)stockName {
    _stockName = stockName;
}
```

Thanks for reply

Comment: **Yes**. these both are same, you are just aliasing the property name to other names.

Comment: How is 2nd case overriding of default setter? Default setter for `stockName` would be `setStockName:`. `mySetter:`, in this case, is just a method you need to call.

Comment: OH sorry, write wrong code, I'll edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Encapsulating Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)
in "Programming with Objective-C":

> **Note**: The compiler will automatically synthesize an instance variable
>   in all situations where it’s also synthesizing at least one accessor
>   method. If you implement both a getter and a setter for a readwrite
>   property, or a getter for a readonly property, the compiler will
>   assume that you are taking control over the property implementation
>   and won’t synthesize an instance variable automatically.

Since you don't implement a *getter*, the instance variable `_stockName` is synthesized.
For this it is irrelevant if you use the default or a custom name for the setter.

And declaring the property as "strong" implies `__strong` ownership for the
associated instance variable, see ["4.1.1. Property declarations"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#property-declarations)
in the "Clang/ARC" documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ARC` and you specified `strong` access specifier, property will hold a strong reference. ARC will be doing the retain/release. Under `non arc` overriding the accessor method is not like this. You should handle the `retain/release`. By `setter = mySetter:` you are just assigning an alias name to the accessor method. That will not make any difference to the implementation. Both methods are doing same thing. and one more thing `mySetter:` will not be the setter for `stockName` it would be `setStockName`

Answer (score 0):

`stockName` will hold `strong` pointer as you are providing the `property` with `strong` ownership. So in both cases you will get a `strong` pointer reference.

But for the question you have asked you can use `stockName` as an `iVar`, `setter` methods and `getter` methods as

**Question 1**

`iVar` = `stockName`

`getter` = `[self stockName]` or `self.stockName`

`setter` = `[self mySetter:]`

**Question 2**

`iVar` = `stockName`

`getter` = `[self stockName]` or `self.stockName`

`setter` = `self.stockName =` or `[self setStockName:]`